# 'No signal' on ASUS F1A75-M LE

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure

I am trying to build a PC (has worked before) with following specs:

- Asus F1A75-M LE motherboard
- 2 x 4 GB DDR3
- AMD A-Series A8-3850
- ASUS GeForce 210

I'm getting a black screen ('No signal'), when I boot it up. All components seems to work when I try them in another PC, so it seems it may be something with the motherboard somehow. Also tested with different GFX cards and displays. Still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify to processor, 1 Ram stick and VGA, DP, HDMI or other built-in video. Probably smart to have a keyboard. SSD or HDD aren't required, BIOS screen is enough.

I encountered a bad Asus Z170-A, a while ago, ASUS have built-in power-up validation tests, with locator LEDs that step around as the board comes up. Once you trust it, just processor and memory are needed to check the motherboard, PSU, etc. Use the on-board pushbuttons. Sometimes add-on graphics hardware need drivers installed before they give pictures. Sometimes HDMI, etc need drivers. VGA hardware is on the board and probably doesn't need anything added.

My processor, ram, SSD all worked with other motherboards, and I got no start-up LED light show. I obtained another mother board from a local retailer, replaced the non-performing one, all good.

Good luck!